# Strange behavior of QTableView pyqt5

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5, qtableview

I am just getting into PyQt5 framework and got stacked while editing cell in my QTableView table.

I have a model like that:

```
class TableHMQIModel(QAbstractTableModel):

headerLabels = []

def __init__(self, data):
    super(TableHMQIModel, self).__init__()
    self._data = data

def data(self, index, role):
    if role == Qt.DisplayRole:
        # See below for the nested-list data structure.
        # .row() indexes into the outer list,
        # .column() indexes into the sub-list
        return self._data[index.row()][index.column()]

def headerData(self, section, orientation, role=Qt.DisplayRole):
    if orientation == Qt.Horizontal and role == Qt.DisplayRole:
        return self.headerLabels[section]
    return super().headerData(section, orientation, role)

def rowCount(self, index):
    # The length of the outer list.
    return len(self._data)

def columnCount(self, index):
    # The following takes the first sub-list, and returns
    # the length (only works if all rows are an equal length)
    return len(self._data[0])

def setData(self, index, value, role):
    if role == Qt.EditRole and index.column() > 1 and value != "":
        self._data[index.row()][index.column()] = value
        return True
    return False

def flags(self, index):
    # if index.column() > 1:
    #     return Qt.ItemIsSelectable | Qt.ItemIsEnabled | Qt.ItemIsEditable
    return Qt.ItemIsSelectable | Qt.ItemIsEnabled
```

And filling it with data like that:

```
data = [ ["C"+str(key), value[0], value[1], value[2], value[3], self.d_GIIP[int(key)]] for key, value in self.dict_full_HMQI.items()]

    headers = ["Case", "HQMI pressure", "HQMI WUT", "HQMI total", "Cumul. condensate FC", "GIIP"]
    
    try: 
        self.tableHMQImodel = TableHMQIModel(data)
        self.tableHMQImodel.headerLabels = headers
        self.tableHMQI.setModel(self.tableHMQImodel)
    except:
        print("Something went wrong! _tableHQMI method")
```

The problem is when the data is shown in table last column is empty. I checked in debugging mode the data and no data is being missed. Literally all the other tables work fine with the same code, but different names of course.

Table:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h3ISc.png)

Comment: Without knowing the contents of `dict_full_HMQI` it's really impossible to tell you what is wrong here. The fact that you casted the value as a float may be a hint, but for future reference always consider providing a valid [mre] (and be more careful with indentation).

Comment: @musicamante Thanks, i agree. I couldn't provide content of the dict as it's classified thing unfortunately. But what i mentioned is in the debug mode i could access the data for of the last column from the model itself using self.tableHMQImodel._data[1][6] and it showed value as it is in the console (it was float number), but still had some problem in the table.

Comment: You don't need to provide "your" data in the example, as even "fake" data is valid as long as it makes sense in its context: the concept is that you need to provide code that allows us to *reproduce* your issue, which is the exact point of providing an MRE, and it's also a major aspect of debugging: simplify the code to the minimum until you're are able to reproduce the issue no matter what, then find the differences between that and your original code: if you still don't understand it, use that example for the question, otherwise you'll have probably already found the cause on your own.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what exactly was happening, but i just wrapped the value for the last column in float() and it showed up...